# Problema con fecha en SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Mi gestor de BD es postgres.
Simplemente, estoy tratando de obtener un resultado basado en una fecha específica o en un rango de fechas.

Tengo esta tabla:

```
create table detalle_ventas ( 
fecha_venta varchar(100) not null,
codigo_barra int not null,
descripcion varchar(50) not null,
cantidad double precision not null
)
```

Intento obtener la cantidad de venta de una fecha especifica, por ejemplo:

```
select * from detalle_ventas where fecha_venta = '03-12-2018';
```

Pero el resultado siempre es `nulo`, a pesar que esta fecha se encuentra almacenada en la base

Igual utilizando un rango:

```
select * from detalle_ventas where fecha_venta between '03-12-2018' and '03-12-2018';
```

Siempre retorna `nulo`.

Si realizo una consulta normal, obtengo los resultados sin problema.

```
select * from detalle_ventas;
```

[image: Solo tengo un valor en la bd, para probar las sentencias.]

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Las fechas deberías guardarlas siempre en formato año-mes-día para que el orden de texto coincida con el orden de fechas o, mejor aún, en un campo de tipo fecha. Es lógico que te falle en caso contrario.

Comment: coloca las fechas en formato YYYYMMDD (año mes dia) de tipo entero y prueba nuevamente, si necesitas consultar con hora el formato sería string 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS'.

Comment: Además, estás buscando la fecha `03-12-2018` con `select * from detalle_ventas where fecha_venta = '03-12-2018'` y, sin embargo, en esa captura se ve que el contenido es  `3-12-2018`, un texto completamente diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Estás almacenando la *fecha* como una cadena de caracteres, no como una fecha, de tu sentencia `create table`

  > `fecha_venta varchar(100) not null,`

  Se ve claramente el tipo de dato, `varchar`. Con esto, el motor *desconoce* completamente que el dato almacenado es una *fecha* (o cualquier otra cosa). Lo va a tratar como a cualquier otra cadena de caracteres.
- Del `select` que muestras al final, se ve que la *fecha* almacenada es '3-12-2018'
- Tu búsqueda se hace por una cadena de caracteres, pero la *fecha* tiene un formato distinto: '03-12-2018', y por tanto el motor no va a encontrar ninguna coincidencia.

Dicho esto, los motores de base de datos tienen la capacidad de manejar tipos de datos fecha, hora y fecha y hora. Almacenarlos como tal tiene la ventaja de poder hacer *aritmética de fechas* a nivel del motor de base de datos, además que las comparaciones serán siempre sobre el *dato* y no sobre su representación visual, como te has enfrentado en este caso.

En el caso concreto de *postgresql*, de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html), tienes los siguientes tipos de dato:

- `timestamp`, fecha y hora (con o sin zona horaria)
- `date`, solo fecha
- `time`, solo hora
- `interval`, es un intervalo de tiempo

Mi recomendación es que almacenes tus datos en estos, y no como cadenas. Es el equivalente a almacenar un número como cadena o como número.

Answer (score 0):

deberias cambiar el campo de fecha a date:

```
create table detalle_ventas ( 
fecha_venta date not null,
codigo_barra int not null,
descripcion varchar(50) not null,
cantidad double precision not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu SQL tiene dos problemas:

- No haces uso del tipo de campo específico para fechas [`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html#CALSTABLE).
- En caso de usar un campo de tipo texto (`varchar`, `text`, etc) no estás usando el formato básico o extendido de fecha [ISO-8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

El orden alfabético no funciona con las fechas tal y como estás haciendo uso de ellas. Como consecuencia:

- `03-12-2018` es diferente de `3-12-2018`:

  - En particular `03-12-2018` es una fecha anterior a `3-12-2018` porque el primer carácter de la primera fecha (`0`) es menor que el primer carácter de la segunda (`3`).
- `12-12-2019` es una fecha anterior a `23-12-2018`.

  - Esto es debido a que el primer carácter de la primera fecha (`1`) es inferior al primer carácter de la segunda (`2`).

Al no usar el tipo de campo `date` no te sale un error al insertar fechas que puedan ser erróneas en formato o contenido y al no usar el formato ISO recomendado el orden alfabético (o alfanumérico) no coincide con el orden de fechas.

Tal y como has definido el esquema podrías usar campos de texto usando el formato `AAAA-MM-DD` (año de 4 cifras, meses de 2 cifras y días de 2 cifras, todos ellos con ceros de relleno a la izquierda si es necesario):

```
INSERT INTO detalle_ventas (
  fecha_venta, codigo_barra, descripcion, cantidad
) VALUES (
  '2018-12-03', 0, 'descripcion', 1
);
```

Te funcionarían correctamente ambos `SELECT`.

Pero yo, personalmente, te recomendaría pasar el campo al tipo que te he recomendado:

```
ALTER TABLE detalle_ventas
    ALTER COLUMN fecha_venta TYPE date USING fecha_venta::text::date;
```

O bien la definición completa:

```
CREATE TABLE detalle_ventas (
  fecha_venta date not null,
  codigo_barra int not null,
  descripcion varchar(50) not null,
  cantidad double precision not null
);
```

Puedes ver una prueba de concepto en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xpoNWTJyk8NcQGWDmx3sTo/1).